# Необходимо реализовать пользовательскую команду

Tags: python

Есть каталог документов:

```
 documents = [
        {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
        {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
        {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
      ]
```

Нужна команда, которая спросит номер документа и выведет имя человека, которому он принадлежит

Comment: Можете прикрепить свой код? Что не получилось?

Comment: пытаюсь сортировать через ключ и получается ерунда, думаю вообще не в том направлении двигаюсь https://repl.it/HoVy/1

Comment: Попробуйте итерировать по массиву

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
documents = [
        {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
        {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
        {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
      ]
inp = input('Enter number: ')
for elem in documents:
    if elem['number'] == inp:
        print(elem['name'])
```

Вариант с `filter`:

```
foo = lambda num: list(filter(lambda x: x['number'] == str(num), documents))[0]['name']
```

Использование:

```
In [33]: foo(10006)
Out[33]: 'Аристарх Павлов'
```

Comment: большое спасибо!